# using bind method on innerobserable in an angular app for accessing dependencies

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, observable

i have a question regarding clean code and best practices using observables.
I created the function 'loadAllSubstancesFromBackend' which returns an observable, getting all data from the backend using the httpClient of angular.
Also there is a subject, which next values, if there was a change in substances. I subscribe to that observable and use switchMap to refresh the data.

```
// inner observable
private loadAllSubstancesFromBackend(): Observable<ISubstance[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get<ISubstanceDTO[]>(`${environment.FOODLIST_API_URL}/substances`)
}

// outer observable
this.substancesChanged
.pipe(
   switchMap(this.loadAllSubstancesFromBackend.bind(this))
 )
.subscribe();

constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) {}
```

My question is, if there is any way to get rid of this .bind() on the inner observable. Like making the dependency lookup in the inner observable itself an getting rid of the "this".

Please let me know if, i missed anything regrading the community rules.

best regards,
Steffen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you would subscribe to the service call (which returns an observable) and then map that subscription to a subject.

```js
# Shorthand
this.loadAllSubstancesFromBackend().subscribe(this.substancesChanged);

# Manually
this.loadAllSubstancesFromBackend().subscribe(
   next => this.substancesChanged.next(next),
   error => this.substancesChanged.error(error),
   () => this.substancesChanged.complete()
);
```

If you post your entire component and service, I could expand my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was just to knew to JS and Angular in all :)